# Qliksense ::calculated dimension

Tags: qliksense

I created a table column with percentage values using a formula in expression editor in `qliksense`.

Now, I want to plot a bar graph with 4 bars each bar corresponding to count of range of percentage values ( ex, `-100% to 0%` ; `05 to 25%` ; `25% to 50 %` ; `505 to 100%` ) from the column I created. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually for buckets you use class function:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/class.htm

You can add exact original visualization, expression, data model or even qvf so I can answer with more details/solution.